# Python defining a value before if, or if/else?

Tags: python, if-statement

An if/else can be written as such:

```
if <condition>:
    variable = <value>
else:
    variable = <other value>
```

But the same can be achieved by:

```
variable = <other value>
if <condition>:
    variable = <value>
```

Is there a meaningful argument as to which is preferred? Or does it come down to personal preference?

Note: I know in Python you could also do:

```
variable = <value> if <condition> else <other value>
```

I'm only concerned about syntax.

Comment: Related: [Compressing \`x if x else y\` statement in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/14105500)

Comment: Related: [One line if-condition-assignment](//stackoverflow.com/q/7872838)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Apparently my Googling and SO search skills need some honing... But thanks for the links!